# how do I return and use an IDictionary value from method

Tags: c#, idictionary

I'm having trouble figuring out the proper syntax for this.. I have a method like so:

```
public IDictionary<string, object> FindTransactions()
{
    Dictionary<string, object> returnItems = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    //do stuff

    return returnItems;
}
```

I want to assign its return value to a new variables from my consuming code. These aren't quite right:

```
IDictionary returnItems = FindTransactions();
//Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>' to 'System.Collections.IDictionary'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Dictionary<string, object> returnItems2 = FindTransactions();
//Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

...how is this done correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close in both cases:

```
IDictionary<string, object> returnItems2 = FindTransactions();
```

The generic `IDictionary<K,V>` interface does not extend the non-generic `IDictionary` so you can't cast to that, and you can't implicitly cast from an less-derived type (like the interface) to a more derived type (like an implementation), because there's no guarantee that the actual type is a `Dictionary<K, V>`